# Update values in one table from data in another

Tags: sqlite

I have an application using SQLite with two tables a `master` table and a `scheduled` table.

I would like to update a value in the `master` table with the value in the scheduled table if I run a query some time after `due` has occurred. Once the `master` table is updated, I would like to delete those values from the `scheduled` table.

Imagine this is the starting state:

```
Table: master
   id    value 
   ---   -----
   1     "Buy"
   2     "Buy"

Table: scheduled
   key   id   value   due
   ----  ---  ------  -----
   1     1    "Sell"  2018-01-01 12:01:00
   2     2    "Sell"  2018-01-01 12:01:00
   3     1    "Buy"   2019-02-02 13:00:00
```

I'm trying to craft a query where if I run it after `2018-01-01 12:01:00`, I would like to see:

```
Table: master
   id    value 
   ---   -----
   1     "Sell"
   2     "Sell"

Table: scheduled
   key   id   value   due
   ----  ---  ------  -----
   3     1    "Buy"   2019-02-02 13:00:00
```

I'm new the SQLite, the closest I have gotten is the following:

```
UPDATE master
  SET
    value = (SELECT scheduled.value FROM scheduled WHERE scheduled.id = master.id)
  WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM scheduled WHERE scheduled.due >= ?);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, and I'm not even sure where to start on the `DELETE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of the question, I did the following:

Created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE master
(
  m_id INTEGER,
  m_value VARCHAR(4)
);

CREATE TABLE scheduled
(
  key INTEGER,
  s_id  INTEGER,
  s_value VARCHAR(4),
  due TIMESTAMP
);
```

Added some records:

```
INSERT INTO master VALUES (1, 'Buy');
INSERT INTO master VALUES (2, 'Buy');

INSERT INTO scheduled VALUES (1, 1, 'Sell', '2018-01-01 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO scheduled VALUES (2, 2, 'Sell', '2018-01-01 12:00:01');
INSERT INTO scheduled VALUES (3, 1, 'Buy',  '2019-01-01 12:00:00');
```

Then I ran the following query:

```
UPDATE master
SET m_value =
(
  SELECT s_value
  FROM scheduled s
  WHERE s_id = m_id
  AND due <= CURRENT_DATE
);
```

The result of `SELECT * FROM master` after the `UPDATE`:

```
m_id   m_value
   1      Sell
   2      Sell
```

You can find all this on the dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=6ab2d90c3517774c3b18e78ea80fabde). Next time you ask a question, you might find it beneficial to set up a  dbfiddle for those who are trying to solve your issue - help us to help you!

BTW, SQLite (unlike other systems) [doesn't support](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) `UPDATE`s with `JOIN`s. I'm not sure what the standard says about using these, but [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e959fe9850b97959c8eb401e60cd4229) is your example done using a join.

```
UPDATE master
SET m_value = s.s_value
FROM  master m
JOIN scheduled s ON m.m_id = s.s_id
WHERE s.due <= NOW();
```

To answer the second part of the question, do all the work (two separate statements) in one `TRANSACTION` (documentation [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_transactions.htm)). Unfortunately, dbfiddle doesn't appear to support this.  **BUT**, we're in luck, this db-fiddle (note hyphen!) does support `TRANSACTION`s - take a look at the complete answer to your question [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qixreVSBwTArbUSa7VbVJX/0). If my solution doesn't help you, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SQLITE Triggers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to update records from another table when you are inserting or updating records in a table.

Trigger will update `scheduled` table if you are updating records in `master` table